# Element name gcse:searchbox-only cannot be represented as XML 1.0

Tags: html, xml, validation, w3c-validation

I am getting the following error in w3 validator,

```
 Line 62, Column 140: Element name gcse:searchbox-only cannot be represented as XML 1.0.
```

I am using Google search bar inside website which is added by this code,

```
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

Please help out to avoid this error. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael[tm] Smith, the guy who looks after the W3C HTML validator [says here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.w3c.validator/13353):

> It's not an error, it's a warning. And it's emitted because the
>   content is being served as HTML instead of with an XML MIME type, and
>   HTML parsers don't know anything about namespaces -- to put it in XML
>   terms, every element name is a local name -- and so in HTML, the
>   literal name of that element is "g:plusone". And that name can't be
>   represented in XML because XML doesn't allow colons in the local
>   names. So the spirit of the warning is to say, In case you ever want
>   to serve this content as XML instead of HTML, you have an element name
>   in it that's not allowed in XML.

He's talking about the element `g:plusone` but it's the same issue.

But I disagree slightly. Colons are valid in element local names in [XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e804). They're only disallowed in [XML 1.0 + namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-NCName) So the warning message could definitely be improved.

UPDATE: 
I previously offered a workaround based on document.write, but as Jan M points out in the comments, IE has it's own ideas about what to do with elements with a colon in their tag names, so it didn't work there. Instead, I recommend following Jan's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: this trick works on Firefox but on IE it refuses to load the search box

Answer (score 19):

I found this answer hidden in the google docs:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5

**HTML5-valid div tags**

You can use HTML5-valid div tags as long as you observe these guidelines:

- The class attribute must be set to gcse-XXX
- Any attributes must be prefixed with data-.

For example:

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-resultsUrl="http://www.example.com" data-newWindow="true" data-queryParameterName="search" >
```

Comment: except that this code fragment, which I also found, does not render a search box on html5 validator on an asp.net C# form.  Using the top method renders an Unrecognized namespace 'gcse' warning.

Comment: Well, it works for me, so perhaps you have something on your C# from that interferes

Answer (score 8):

You could always use `<div class="gcse-search"></div>` instead of `<gcse:search></gcse:search>`, then the error will go away from the w3c validator.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple, Don't use directly the **google search tag** in html page.
*Just place a simple javascript code to insert the **google search tag** in html by **javascript's innerhtml** option*.

Here is the example:

```
<div id="gsearch"></div>

<script>
   var gcseDiv = document.getElementById('gsearch');
   gcseDiv.innerHTML = '<gcse:search></gcse:search>'
</script>
```

After this line you can write or paste your google search code which will be same as below

```
      <script>
      (function() {
                var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx';
                var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                gcse.async = true;
                gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
              })();

      </script>
```

**Suggestion:** Just put the above div and both script in a single parent div and manage css for parent div only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too simple, but I worked around the problem by just putting this inside and at the end of the javascript:

```
document.write('<gcse:search><\/gcse:search>');
```

And removed

It works in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari and validates.

Comment: Are you sure about that `</script>` all by itself? Looks like one line too many.

Comment: document.write('<gcse:search><\/gcse:search>');
  </script>

Comment: And remove <gcse:search></gcse:search>

Comment: To have code formatted properly in answers, start the line with four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code if you only want to display the searchbox (without the resultsbox) using a DIV:

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox-only"></div>
```